# Update ListView items without scrolling ListView

Tags: android, listview, notifydatasetchanged

I use ListView to show my items.
The matter is when I want to update or delete some items, I have to clear ArrayList assigned to ListViewAdapter and use `notifyDataSetChanged`. This causes ListView to scroll to the bottom. How can I prevent to scroll ListView in this situation?
the ListView is a list of chat messages and I want to update the list every 15 seconds. When a user is reading messages and scrolling up, after refreshing the ListView, it scrolls to the bottom.
I see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example/5092426#5092426).

Comment: Most importantly, why are you still using ListView?

Comment: So help me to improve me. What widget I can use?

Comment: You should be using a `RecyclerView`. [More on that here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)

Comment: Are you using firebase ? If yes i would like to suggest you to use Firebase Recycleradapter .

Comment: Definitely don't use a ListView. Use a `RecyclerView` with a `ListAdapter<T, VH>` and instead of use `notifyDataSetChanged()` pass a new list and let the Listadapter calculate the diff using `DiffUtil.Callback`